# FreeSwitch Inbound DID Fails "User_Not_Registered"

Tags: sip, voip, freeswitch

I am using FreeWitch VOIP server. I am receiving an inbound DID. However, my SIP Trace shows
error "User_Not_Registered" see (sip trace log below). The device never receives the call and dial-plan defaults to voicemail.

Running command list_user reveals nothing and sofia_contact reveals "User_Not_Registered".

Show Registrations - reveals:
9856937967,domain.com,8vSSYnN7QcIRw5u3nfg5pA..,sofia/sip-ip/sip:9856937967@92.7.187.203:39706;transport=UDP;rinstance=ec30c6121794d08f,1615480452,92.7.187.203,39706,udp,astpp.domain.com,

1 total.

Then I ran command below:
sofia status profile sip-ip  reg

## Registrations:

Call-ID:        S3gXf-fjxpA9ws47L8bh9w..
User:           9856937967@domain.com
Contact:        "" sip:9856937967@92.7.187.203:62990;transport=UDP;rinstance=df94511808fbcf07
Agent:          Z 5.4.9 rv2.10.11.7
Status:         Registered(UDP)(unknown) EXP(2021-03-11 11:03:29) EXPSECS(102)
Ping-Status:    Reachable
Ping-Time:      0.00
Host:           astpp.domain.com
IP:             92.7.187.203
Port:           62990
Auth-User:      9856937967
Auth-Realm:     domainl.com
MWI-Account:    9856937967@domainl.com

Total items returned: 1

This is my Sip Trace: https://pastebin.freeswitch.org/view/247199c4

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Means that user 9856937967 did not registered.

Suppose your sofia profile name is "internal-5060", please check:

```
sofia status profile internal-5060 reg
```